# Mirroring a directory of a website

Tags: website, mirroring

I want to download the classic *“Starting FORTH”* book, which seems to be out of print, but available [here](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/) for free. That is, I want to use a site-ripper to download all html pages inside the  `forth.com/starting-forth/` subdirectory (and only there) which are linked from the index and also *all* images used in those pages regardless of their location.

I tried to do it with httrack, but it seems to be quite [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244419/httrack-how-to-download-folders-only-from-a-certain-subfolder-level), because I would manually have to add all subdirectories of `forth.com/starting-forth/`.

How should I proceed? Windows or Linux solutions are good, though I would prefer the latter.

Comment: Did you try `wget`? BTW  read *all* the options and search some command-line example online. It seems there is no robot.txt rules on that site. `wget -p -k http://www.example.com/sub-dir' Check for  the option to remain on the site and to avoid to go up to that starting directory.

Comment: Try [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/), it designed to do what you want. It working on both - Linux and Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `wget`.

```
wget -r -np -k https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/
```

- `-r` recursive
- `-np` don't follow links to parent directories
- `-k` to make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to local files

(From [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100573))

(Edit) The final commands:

```
wget -r -np -k -p --domains forth.com,netdna-ssl.com -H https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/
```

- `-p` causes wget to download all files necessary to render the page (images, sounds, stylesheets)
- `--domains` is used to set the domains where content will be downloaded from. This will normally just be the website and a cdn.
- `-H` allows downloading content from other hosts (the ones you put in `--domain`).

`find . -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i 's/\?ver=/_ver=/g' {} +`

This searches all html files and replaces references to `?ver` with `_ver` because when wget downloads any files where the url contains something like `jquery.colorbox.js?ver=1.1.0` it needs to replace the `?` with `_` to save it as a file.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats I tried it locally and as far as I can tell all the images have been saved.

Comment: for me not and I used exactly your command. Of course they appear in the browser, because you're online. But do a search in the local mirror directory for image files, there are none.

Comment: ok, I read the wget manpage. This one `wget -r -np -k -p  --domains forth.com,netdna-ssl.com -H https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/` kind of works. At least it downloads the image files. There is still something not quite right with the layout of the mirrored site :-( :-( but it's okay, it's at least *usable* now if you're truly offline. If you know how to fix it completely, please let me know. Thanks so far for your help.

Comment: As it seems, wget replaces the "?" in files like colorbox.css?ver=4.7.2 with a "_". You could run something like `find . -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i 's/\?ver=/_ver=/g' {} +`